# FB SDk Get users page info

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this piece of code to get a users info from FB

```
if ($user) {
try {
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}
```

This code is working perfectly, Now i need to add permissions to get a users page that he/she has created on his profile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just 2 steps:

1. get "manage_pages" permission from user
2. Get all account information by calling `FB.api(/me/accounts)`

Way two, get it from Fql query:

```
SELECT page_id, type from page_admin WHERE uid=me()
```

page_admin documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/)

Comment: I have added /me/accounts but its not working, can you write some code here.

Comment: try to find out something like this $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email,'here_add_all_permissions'));

Comment: Hi, Thanks, its working now. But one little problem after adding all these things that you have mentioned i am now only getting pages data and not users profile.

Comment: Glad to know it is working. Please let me see the code to say what is your new problem..:)